# Is there any way to use multiple language for Joi Validation?

Tags: express, joi

I really want to return multiple language for error message, but dont know how to do it.
Anyone can give me a suggest please.

```
  const schema = {
    email: Joi.string().email().label("Email Address").error(err => {
      err.forEach(error => {
        switch(error.type){
          case "string.base":
            error.message = "must be a string";
            break;
          case "string.email":
            error.message = "must be an email";
            break;
        }
      });
      return err;
    }),
    password: Joi.string()
  }
```